# Enforce continuous numbers with row trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with a 'position' column named 'p#'. All values in the position column must be continuous, i.e. to insert an entry with p# = 2, there must be a p# =1 entry. The method used has to be done with a row trigger that raises an application error if the inserted data is not continuous.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ContinuousPosition
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON Position
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    prevPos NUMBER(8);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO prevPos FROM Position WHERE p# = (:NEW.p# - 1);

    IF prevPos = 0 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'testError');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

This works for the first time I try to insert a new row, however once one row has been successfully inserted, this trigger fires no matter what I try to insert next.

Comment: Increment it using a `sequence`  or use `IDENTITY` column (Oracle 12c +) . Read https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonumber-and-identity and https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1

Comment: This is a practice question, and it states it has to be done with row trigger, and it has to raise an application error if the trigger occurs

Comment: "This works for the first time I try to insert a new row"-  So, even the next time it is going to contain zero rows and unless you disable the trigger it won't allow you to insert the first row.

Comment: Yes, so say there is row p# = 1, I insert p# = 2 and it works. If I then try to insert p# = 3, it triggers for some reason. If I then run the trigger code again and replace the trigger, it'll then let me do insert p# = 3, but I won't be able to insert p# = 4.

Comment: So, how will you ensure it to be continuous when someone deletes a record?

Comment: I don't know. The practice questions is: Implement and comprehensively test a row trigger that verifies the following
consistency constraint.
“The value of position number must be continuous”. Later on it says "Whenever SQL statement
violates the consistency constraint a trigger must return ORA-… error message. Use a
procedure RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR to return ORA-… error message."

Comment: Did the solution i gave worked for you? . At least give a feedback if it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already told in the comments, you should prefer incrementing the column using an Oracle `SEQUENCE` in the `Trigger` or use `IDENTITY` column (Oracle 12c +) .

Refer  https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonumber-and-identity

and https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1

Furthermore, your `TRIGGER` on it's own will not work the first time, unlses you have disabled it. you should add a condition such as this to allow the insert to work normally the first time.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO   tot_count
FROM   POSITION;

IF tot_count != 0 THEN
...--Other statements
```

The second problem is that you should `commit` after **each** `INSERT` for it to reflect the values of the table in an `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`.

The third problem is how will you ensure it to be continuous when someone deletes a record?

Address these issues and use the Trigger only if required in real-time.

Comment: Thanks, committing after each INSERT allowed it to work. However the trigger does work the first time, no need to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned about using sequences and/or identity clauses, but there is something more fundamental here with the trigger approach.

**It wont work.**

There are two reasons why the trigger will not work

1. You cannot run a query in a trigger that references the triggering table.  You will get an error saying "table is mutating", so right from the start you are going to have problems
2. The concept breaks down totally in any kind of real database
   situation, that is, where there is more than 1 user in the system.
   Let's say that there are 10 records currently in the table, and 2
   users want to add a record. Both of them will issue a count(*), both
   will get '10' and hence both will try to add a row with an
   identifier of 11.

I've done an entire video on this common flaw with triggers here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdU92bsByOQ

but simply ... don't use triggers for this.  And if it is a course lesson, this should be pointed out to the instructor as well - it's a terrible practice to be teaching this approach (for this problem).